# Install Panda3d to run with python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, panda3d

I am running Ubuntu 10.04, I have python installed and running fine. When I installed pand3d from the deb package from the site and tried to run an sample. Like it is describe in this page:

> http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Installing_Panda3D_in_Linux

I got the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "Tut-Asteroids.py", line 13, in
>
> import direct.directbase.DirectStart
>
> ImportError: No module named direct.directbase.DirectStart

In the same page as above there is a description to how to solve this error. But I don't understand what do I need to do.

Can any one tell-me what do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. I had two pythons installed. One in /usr/bin and the other in /usr/local/bin. Turn out I needed to use the /usr/bin version to run what I needed. Hope this helps other!